# Ratelimiting for Flux flatMap()

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, hazelcast

An application I am working on is leveraging Spring Webflux + Hazelcast IQueue for inbound data processing.

A problem I am facing is that the application would be overloaded during the peak hour. The situation occurred when processing those messages (consumed from Hazelcast IQueue and converted them as Flux) by Flux.flatMap().

My question is that, is there anyway to accurately know how "busy" the flatMap processing happened inside? So that I could write some code to slow down the message consumption from Hazelcast distributed queue.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation the simplest way to solve the problem is to limit concurrency. By default, flatMap will process `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE = 256` number of in-flight inner sequences.

You could control concurrency `flatMap(item -> process(item), concurrency)` or use `concatMap` operator if you want to process sequentially. Check [flatMap(..., int concurrency, int prefetch)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-int-) for details.

Comment: thanks for your comment! It's true that leveraging "concurrency" parameter could help to limit the max concurrency, but as more and more request comes into the flatMap(item -> process(item), concurrency), will it possible end up with out of memory?

Comment: Backpressure mechanism in Reactive Streams would help to avoid such situation. Check https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#reactive.backpressure for details. 
Also, it's important to understand prefetch concept that allows to avoid "round-trips and is beneficial if producing the elements before they are requested is not too costly". Both `concurrency` & `prefetch` are configurable on `flatMap` level and allows to tune operator if required.

Comment: Recently, I found a link where shares some examples regarding back pressure of reactor flatmap.
https://pandepra.medium.com/project-reactors-flatmap-and-backpressure-fba97472d625